# Windows XP: error loading operation system

Tags: windows-xp, ubuntu-10.04, bootloader, multi-boot

I was trying to dual boot my windows machine with ubuntu 10.04. While I was making swap space, something bad happened and my system automatically restarted. Now it shows, "Error loading operating system". Please help me in recovering my windows partition. Its very urgent. Now ubuntu is also not installed and i dont know what happened to windows.

Answer (score 1):

**Note:**

I **strongly** suggest you make an image of the whole disk before doing **anything** on it, as any change can only make it worse.

There are many things that could have gone wrong, but take a look at the procedures outlined here:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MultiOSBoot

Basically, start using Live CD and try to recover. If you did not do any damage (like replacing Windows partition with your swap partition or something similar), this should be OK.

Be **very** careful about what you are doing - a small typo can ruin everything, even if there's a chance for you to fully recover.

Comment: Say if I have made swap space over windows, will I be able to recover my data using testDIsk. Please provide me some way to recover my data. Its really very important

Comment: Unfortunately, if you overwrote your Windows partition, the chances of data recovery are probably very slim. But let's not jump to conclusions - if you used the usual OS installation and followed the instructions, you probably did not. I am more keen to suspect you just did not have the boot loader installed as the installation crashed in the meantime. Boot the Live CD, open the terminal and do `fdisk -l` - if you see any of the partitions listed as `HPFS/NTFS` or similar, you are probably good, especially if you also see `Linux swap` and such.

Comment: From LiveCD, fdisk -l shows nothing.

Comment: Try `sudo fdisk -l`

Comment: Ya I think I have lost all data, fdisk is showing only two partions now: one as /dev/sda1 "Linux Swap / Solaris" and other one as /dev/sda2 "Compaq diagnostics"

Comment: I would suggest you take it to somebody who knows Linux, who might be able to take a look and possibly save something - this is beyond superuser.com. There is also a lot of software that may be able to help, take a look here for example: http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/232360-45-which-software-recover-deleted-partition. Note that **any** writing to the disk can only make things worse, so if you can, make an image of the disk first, then try to do different things. All depends on what happened - you might have most of the data laying there or you may have nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I do hope that you have not by mistake allocated the swap partition on top of Windows.

Use [Paragon Partition Manager 11 Free Edition](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/pm-express/) to have a look at your partition table and let us know what you see. If there are any interesting screens, you might even take photos of them with a digital camera and post them here. With this utility you can also manipulate partitions, but that is for when we decide what to manipulate.

As general comment: You can use a boot CD such as [GParted Live](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php) to have a look at your partitions. 
It contains [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) which is designed to help recover lost partitions and/or make non-booting disks bootable again.

Have a try and let us know how it goes. (Just be careful not to destroy the disk further.)

Comment: Say if I have made swap space over windows, will I be able to recover my data using testDIsk. Please provide me some way to recover my data. Its really very important

Comment: Try first Partition Manager 11 Free Edition (link above) to see the partitions table, and we can then advice you more.

Answer (score 0):

How were you making swap space? Was this part of the Ubuntu install process or were you trying some other way?

If the Windows install is important to keep you could try booting from a Windows CD and using the repair/recovery process.

Comment: I was trying to make swap space by myself but within ubuntu installation. I specified some 1500 MB for swap space and then it was showing progress bar for resizing partition.

Comment: If Ubuntu resized your Windows partition, this is bad.

Answer (score 0):

Your Master Boot Record (MBR) may be damaged. Here are some potentially helpful links for fixing this type of problem:

1. [Windows XP wont boot - MBR problem?](http://www.softwaretipsandtricks.com/forum/windows-xp/3423-windows-xp-wont-boot-mbr-problem.html)
2. [How to fix MBR in Windows XP and Vista](http://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/fix-mbr-xp-vista/)

Google searching for `"Error loading operating system" mbr` and `fix mbr xp` may also bear fruit. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you overwrote the Windows partition with swap. If you're lucky, you only overwrote the boot sector - if so use a Windows XP CD and select the "repair installation option".

If not, you may be able to find some data using several available tools, such as Test Disk: http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk